# Comparing two different lists of customers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two lists to compare. One is a list of customers that have made a payment in the last 45 days, and the second are customers that have made a payment in the last 12 months

Query 1

```
select i.trandate, i.tranid, c.companyname, c.customer_id, tl.amount
  , '12 Mo Customers' 'Type'
from ns.tpayment i
join ns.Customers c on c.customer_id = i.ENTITY_ID
join ns.transaction_lines tl on i.transaction_id = tl.transaction_id
join ns.accounts a on a.account_id = tl.account_id
where a.name = 'General Checking' and DATEDIFF(month,i.trandate, GETDATE()) <= 12
```

Query 2

```
select i.trandate, i.tranid, c.companyname, c.customer_id, tl.amount
  , '45 Day Customers' 'Type'
from ns.tpayment i
join ns.Customers c on c.customer_id = i.ENTITY_ID
join ns.transaction_lines tl on i.transaction_id = tl.transaction_id
join ns.accounts a on a.account_id = tl.account_id
where a.name = 'General Checking' and DATEDIFF(day,i.trandate, GETDATE()) <= 45
```

I need to compare the list generated from the first query against the list generated by the second query to see who has made a payment in the last 12 months but HAS NOT made a payment in the last 45 days.

A bit stuck on the next step, hoping someone has an idea on how best to accomplish that in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select c.companyname, c.customer_id
from ns.tpayment i join
     ns.Customers c
     on c.customer_id = i.ENTITY_ID join
     ns.transaction_lines tl
     on i.transaction_id = tl.transaction_id join
     ns.accounts a
     on a.account_id = tl.account_id
where a.name = 'General Checking' and 
      DATEDIFF(month, i.trandate, 
GETDATE()) <= 12
group by c.companyname, c.customer_id
having DATEDIFF(day, max(i.trandate), GETDATE()) > 45;
```

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, these are all the customers then that made a payment in the last 12 months (the where clause)  but not in the last 45 days (the having clause)